# How is it grammatical to end a sentence with ばかり?

Tags: grammar, particle-ばかり

In my bilingual dictionary, ばかり is listed as a particle. Yet in a [tutorial on ばかり](https://www.tofugu.com/japanese/tokoro-bakari/), I came across the following sentence:

> 車を買ったばかり。
>
> I just bought a car.

What's weird to me is that the sentence ends in a particle (ばかり). How is this grammatical?

- Is this just a slangy way of saying this sentence?
- Perhaps ばかり doubles as a noun, and there is an implicit だ (copula) being dropped at the end?
- ...something else?

Comment: related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/56681/is-desu-needed-at-the-end-of-every-single-sentence-also-can-you-add-end-partic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ばかり can work also like a no-adjective (which [is a noun](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/2771/5010)), just as はず, ため and so on can. So yes, this is a sentence with an implicit だ/です. The canonical version of this sentence is (私は)車を買ったばかり**です** or (私は)車を買ったばかり**だ**.

Since ばかり can work as a no-adjective, you can say this, too:

- 車を買ったばかりの男
  a man who just bought a car